# rvm rails can't find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am using RVM 1.1.6, ruby 1.8.7-P302 and have installed l the linkedin gem with:
gem install linkedin

- the gem appears in the `gem list --local` listing
- and in the GEM_PATH directory
- in irb `require 'linkedin'` returns true

But when I run `script/server`, I get `Missing these required gems: linkedin` and I am running out of hair to tear out. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `config.gem 'linkedin'` in the `config/environment.rb` file

Comment: double-check your ruby and gem versions : which ruby, which gem? Also, did you do a `rake gems:install` ?

Comment: which ruby: .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby;  which gem: .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/gem;  And did do rake gems:install